# Singleton и static class

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Вот решил посмотреть, что за чудо такое этот Singleton. И сразу возник вопрос: а чем он лучше статик класса? От статик класса объекты нельзя сделать, да и наследоваться от него тоже нельзя.
И вообще какова область применения синглтона?
В многопоточном приложении будут возникать проблемы при использовании статик класса?

Вот, к примеру два одинаковых класса, но реализованных в виде синглтона и статик:

```
public sealed class MyMathSingleton
{
    private static readonly Object obj_lock = new Object();
    private static MyMathSingleton instance = null;

    private MyMathSingleton()
    { }

    public static MyMathSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance != null) return instance;
            Monitor.Enter(obj_lock);
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref instance, new MyMathSingleton());
            Monitor.Exit(obj_lock);
            return instance;                
        }
    }

    public int A_plus_B(int a, int b)
    { return a + b; }
}

public static class MyMathStatic
{
    public static int A_plus_B(int a, int b)
    { return a + b; }
}
```

PS. реализацию синглтона взял отсюда: [Три возраста паттерна Singleton](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147373/). Правда там автор пишет, что создание инстанса должно выглядеть так, иначе чуда не произойдет:

```
Singleton temp = new Singleton();
Interlocked.Exchange(ref instance, temp);
```

А у меня такая запись вполне нормально кушается компилятором:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref instance, new MyMathSingleton());
```

---

**UPD 14.05.27**

Допустим у меня в приложении есть форма, с помощью которой в одну из таблиц БД заносится новая запись или же запись редактируется. Эта форма мне нужна только одна, скажу больше - если их будет несколько, то могут возникнуть проблемы при редактировании записи. В данном случае целесообразно реализовать класс формы в виде синглтона?

Comment: подпишусь-ка на вопросы с тегом `дзен` :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ: (оффтопик) [правильная статья насчёт имплементации синглтона](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Имплементация, которую вы приводите, неверна, т. к. между строчками

    if (instance != null) return instance;

и

    Monitor.Enter(obj_lock);

поле `instance` может быть инициализировано из другого потока.

Comment: >В данном случае целесообразно реализовать класс формы в виде синглтона?

по-моему, это весьма сомнительное применение данному патерну. Во всяком случае судя по вышеуказанным данным

Comment: @teanЫЧ: В принципе, ничто не мешает различными экземплярами одной и той же формы редактировать _две_ совершенно разные таблицы. (Ваш код формы, надеюсь, содержит только UI, и не знает ничего о самой таблице.) Поэтому решать на уровне формы, сколько штук их должно быть — неправильно. Пусть уровень бизнес-логики решает, сколько форм нужно, и какие таблицы в них будут редактироваться.

Comment: @VladD "Ваш код формы, надеюсь, содержит только UI, и не знает ничего о самой таблице". Это, конечно интересно, но в таком случае надо делать динамическое формирование UI на форме, в зависимости от таблицы, запись которой надо отредактировать/добавить. Ведь таблички-то разные.  

-----  

Если просто разместить datagridview то это будет несложно реализовать, но это будет крайне некрасиво при большИх таблицах.

Comment: А если делать красивую форму с лэйблами, текстбоксами и комбобоксами. То нужно либо их сразу задавать (а тогда все формы будут разными. И смысл не давать знать форме, с какой таблицей она работает, если все равно ни для какой другой таблицы ее использовать не получится?), либо делать хитрую процедуру формирования на лету.

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Не знаю, как с этим у WinForms, а в WPF [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid) автоматически подстраивается под тип таблицы.

В любом случае, с таблицей имеет право общаться лишь модель, view имеет право лишь отображать данные (из модели или VM, в зависимости от выбранного архитектурного паттерна) и передавать контроллеру/VM пользовательский ввод. В такой постановке view может быть отконфигурировано контроллером для конкретного типа таблицы (а может и самоотконфигурироваться).

---
Но это уже тема для отдельного обсуждения.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Он не лучше и не хуже статического класса, у них предназначение совершенно разное. Статический класс - это по сути пространство имен для функций/констант/etc. Синглтон - это сущность, которая может существовать в одном экземпляре.  То есть как говорится, "все совпадения случайны". Задача синглтона - это гарантия существования только одного экземпляра **с учетом многопоточности** (без таковой он становится дыркой от бублика), тогда как статический класс по сути можно считать синтаксическим сахаром - C# полностью объектно-ориентирован, а потому наличие "самостоятельных" функций/переменных/констант, не заключенных в класс, в нем не допускается.  Эту проблему достаточно элегантно решают статические классы.
Ну а тот факт, что и для того и другого невозможно создание экземпляров (точнее, для синглтона возможно, но не напрямую) и от обоих нельзя наследоваться - это всего лишь похожие следствия из двух разных идей.

Приведенный вами пример со статическим классом мягко говоря не в тему - он не предоставляет никакого экземпляра "в единственном числе", как раз-таки являясь "неймспейсом для функции". А потому отождествлять его с синглтоном некорректно - пропадает весь смысл идеи. Примерно то же самое можно сказать и про сам синглтон из вашего примера -  вариант, предложенный Рихтером, вы дополнили ненужным методом A_plus_B (он не имеет отношения к самой идее и не влияет на "одиночность").
Собственно, еще стоит упомянуть, что синглтон, как паттерн проектирования - сущность не имеющая непосредственного отношения к конкретному языку, а статический класс - это всего лишь особенность ряда языков, в том числе и C#.

Comment: Теперь ясно, спасибо. Просто я подменил понятия, и сам себя запутал.

Comment: хотя, стоп, почему это от синглтона нельзя наследоваться? Вполне можно

Comment: @DreamChild: Хм. А какой смысл наследоваться от синглтона? Если `S` — синглтон, значит, в любой момент можно создать (единственный) экземпляр `S`. Если `S1` наследуется от `S`, то создание экземпляра `S1` есть в то же время и создание экземпляра `S` (т. к. `S1` _is-a_ `S`).

Comment: @VladD речь о том, что от синглтона **можно** наследоваться. Имеет ли смысл - уже другой вопрос. Это было сказано применительно к утверждению ТCа, что 

>От статик класса объекты нельзя сделать, да и наследоваться от него тоже нельзя

Comment: @DreamChild: А, понял :) Вы правы.

Answer (score 14):

Re: ваш PS

Автор статьи на Хабре самоуверенно порет чушь.

Начнём с главного: его код синглтона **не потокобезопасен**! Разбор:

```
if(instance != null) return instance;
// (*)
Monitor.Enter(s_lock);
Singleton temp = new Singleton();
Interlocked.Exchange(ref instance, temp);
Monitor.Exit(s_lock);
return instance;
```

Пусть поток 1 начинает выполнять приведённый код. `instance` в этот момент есть `null`, так что первая проверка проходит, и выполнение доходит до строки (*).

Пусть в этот момент произойдёт переключение контекста (это ведь возможно, правильно?), и начинает выполняться второй поток. Он точно так же проверяет `instance`, проходит начальную проверку, пробегает через (*), получает `lock`, создаёт экземпляр синглтона, записывает его в `instance`, отпускает `lock` и выходит. Второй поток получает ссылку на instance только что созданного синглтона.

Теперь управление получает первый поток. Он точно так же получает `lock`, создаёт **второй** экземпляр синглтона, записывает его в `instance`, затирая старое значение, отпускает `lock` и выходит. Первый поток получает ссылку на другой объект.

Катастрофа.

Теперь по мелочам. Разработчики .NET [не просто так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix) сделали `lock(obj)` синонимом `Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken)`, а не просто `Monitor.Enter(obj)`. Вариант с `Monitor.Enter(obj)` работает неправильно в случае, если возможны исключения. Поэтому замена `lock` на явный `Monitor.Enter` — ухудшение.

Ещё большее ухудшение — отказ от try/catch. Без базара, без try/catch быстрее, только код получается неправильный. (Впрочем, если правильный код нам не нужен, без `lock`'а было бы ещё быстрее.) Если по каким-то причинам конструктор `Singleton`'а выбросит исключение (а это может быть не только деление на 0, но и `TypeLoadException`, например), то `s_lock` останется залоченным навсегда — deadlock.

Затем, автор критикует правильные, рекомендованные экспертами (а Jon Skeet — мегаэксперт) имплементации под совершенно надуманными предлогами. По поводу подхода «через readonly поле» автор пишет:

> Конструктор может быть только статичным. Это особенность компилятора — если конструткор не статичен, то тип будет помечен как beforefieldinit и readonly создадутся одновременно со static-ами.

Это фактически неверно, автор судя по всему просто не понял, что именно написал Jon. У синглтона есть нестатический конструктор, просто явный статический конструктор должен *присутствовать*. Между «статический конструктор должен присутствовать» и «конструктор может быть только статичным» огромная разница.

Правильная, остроумная, каноническая реализация синглтона с вложенным классом удостоилась лишь замечания «Недостатки у него те же самые, что у любого другого кода, который использует nested-классы». Мне неизвестны недостатки вызванные одним лишь наличием вложенных классов. Если мне кто-либо сообщит, готов изменить своё мнение.

Наконец, самое концептуально верное решение с `Lazy<T>` критикуется за то, что оно «не работает с потоками», а используют структуры языка, которые «обманывают интерпретатор». Здесь неверно вообще всё, кроме союзов и предлогов. Начнём с того, что C# — компилируемый язык, интерпретатора C# не существует. Затем, никакого обмана нет: `Lazy<T>` работает строго как обещает его документация. То, что его поведение отличается от поведения других классов — не обман и не трюк. При желании то же самое можно заимплементировать самому вручную.

Затем, правильным при реализации синглтона является не многопоточность или прочие технические мелочи, а простой инвариант: как бы синглтон не использовался, всегда гарантировано наличие **не более одного экземпляра** синглтона на AppDomain. Именно это гарантируется классом `Lazy<T>`. Используются ли при этом специальные механизмы для поддержки многопоточности или свойства языка, никому не интересно. Главное — чтобы семантика единственного экземпляра была выдержана. Именно это гарантирует класс `Lazy<T>`, абстрагируя нас от деталей реализации. И именно поэтому такая имплементация — самая правильная.

Вывод: не все статьи на Хабре одинаково полезны.

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже посмотрел правильную статью, которую вы скидывали :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Угу. Но всё же статью надо разобрать, а то люди прочитают её и подумают, что код оттуда хороший.

Answer (score 6):

Стоит добавить пару слов про тестирование.

```
class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private IDataService _dataService;

    public IdentityService(IDataService dataService)
    {
       // IDataService, естественно, интерфейс
       _dataService = dataService;
       ...
    }
}
```

Довольно часто синглтон представляет какую-либо составную часть большой системы, т. е. является как-бы слоем или узлом. Так, например, `IdentityService` отвечает за аутентификацию/авторизацию пользователей. В то же время, `IdentityService` зависит от другого сервиса-синглтона `IDataService` (в принципе, `IdentityService` не знает, что `IDataService` синглтон (он может им и не являться, это только для примера)).

Здесь как раз и видно "преимущество" синглтонов перед статиками - мы в любой можем подменить передаваемую в конструктор реализацию `IDataService` так, что это никак не повлияет на работу `IdentityService`. И так, если нам нужно будет написать юнит-тесты к `IdentityService`, то мы просто подменим `IDataService` на какой-нибудь `FakeDataService` с методами-заглушками. Собственно, это уже принципы Dependency Injection.

---

Кстати, обычно временем жизни экземпляров занимаются специальные IoC-контейнеры, т. е. при инициализации приложения вы просто указываете какой сервис сколько должен жить.