# Не удается загрузить куки из файла

Tags: c#, winforms, cookie

Есть следующий код:

```
private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true
};
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

public Class1()
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 UBrowser/6.0.1308.1016 Safari/537.36");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
}
```

Сохранение кук в виде `json`:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filename = Path.Combine(path, "test/cookies.bin");

if (File.Exists(filename)) File.Delete(filename);

var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://site.ru/"));

using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, cookies);
```

Загрузка кук:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filename = Path.Combine(path, "test/cookies.bin");

using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
var cookies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Cookie>>(fs);
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
    handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
}
```

Куки в файле:

```
[{"Comment":"","CommentUri":null,"HttpOnly":true,"Discard":false,"Domain":"site.ru","Expired":false,"Expires":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Name":"__RequestVerificationToken","Path":"/","Port":"","Secure":true,"TimeStamp":"2020-10-09T13:33:07.1633063+03:00","Value":"D4cK7wXeq6KThXJG0uZJ8gxUZQ_jGr1pNUwrCuJEhlKVeQHiLQzbvdkZXxmcWT8oYRt4ipPUes4D0dMTxbgY_2yZnJUZxM03F7n0AVtFShU1","Version":0},{"Comment":"","CommentUri":null,"HttpOnly":true,"Discard":false,"Domain":"site.ru","Expired":false,"Expires":"2020-10-11T13:33:08+03:00","Name":".ASPXAUTH","Path":"/","Port":"","Secure":false,"TimeStamp":"2020-10-09T13:33:07.6753356+03:00","Value":"824040565E5BCCD7A57ECDFC3BF4A3D5BEFF477161636356924B0340E53F1527470E6513BE272EDB9392A05C652542ED27F5A001D92DFDE5F395BD1D75708F60CCF2DE2D40ACDF1B8D82743D8CED67713FE85653BB04716B534FA3CEAD261FC9BED4BA50A21C9D2C989FDB2EF1D9ADE4","Version":0}]
```

`GET` запрос через браузер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`GET` запрос через программу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что после загрузки кук я не получаю ту страницу, которую должен, а получаю страницу авторизации. Судя по всему, проблема в том, что у меня как бы "не загружается" кука `.ASPXAUTH`.. и на изображение из браузера видно другие куки (`_ym_uid` и другие..), я не могу понять, они обязательны или нет?

Ранее с куками дел не имел, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

**UPD:**

```
private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true
};
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

public HttpManager()
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 UBrowser/6.0.1308.1016 Safari/537.36");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");
}
```

Получаю куки теперь так:

```
var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetAllCookies();
```

Загружаю так:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Cookie>>(fs);
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
    // не загружать, если кука заэкспайрилась
    if (!cookie.Expired && (cookie.Expires == DateTime.MinValue || cookie.Expires > DateTime.Now))
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
}
```

Этот класс позаимствовал по ссылке которую написали в комментариях:

```
public static class CookieContainerExtensions
{
    // Забирает все куки из контейнера
    public static CookieCollection GetAllCookies(this CookieContainer container)
    {
        CookieCollection allCookies = new CookieCollection();
        IDictionary domains = (IDictionary)container.GetType()
            .GetRuntimeFields()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_domainTable")
            .GetValue(container);

        foreach (object field in domains.Values)
        {
            IDictionary values = (IDictionary)field.GetType()
                .GetRuntimeFields()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "m_list")
                .GetValue(field);

            foreach (CookieCollection cookies in values.Values)
            {
                allCookies.Add(cookies);
            }
        }
        return allCookies;
    }
}
```

К сожалению, на деле получаю то, что получал ранее. Видать, я что-то упускаю из виду..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/958900/206435 может поможет

Comment: [Еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567), точнее не просто пример, а берите и используйте. :)

Comment: `_ym` - это яндекс.метрика. `_ga` - гуглоаналитика.

Comment: Тут может быть несколько причин: 1. Печенька "протухла" - у вас, например, она до `13:33:07`. 2. Не совпадают ключи - иногда делают так, что сайт требует 2+ ключа доступа и они связаны, и вот если один из них битый, то сайт не считает это успешной авторизацией. 3. - Неверно указан `URI` - Cookie очень сильно завязаны на адресе, особенно в C# и, если печенька для `.site.ru` (точка в начале), то это не равно просто `site.ru` (без точки), проверьте, правильный-ли вы адрес получаете и задаете при сохранении/восстановлении. По поводу "лишнее" - скорей всего да, как и все, что у вас в `Class1`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, домен проверил - у меня он везде начинается так `e.site.ru` (правильно), в коде именно так везде и указано. Единственное, что я заметил сейчас, это то, что когда в браузере перед авторизацией ставлю чекбокс `Запомнить`, то в `POST` запрос отправляется так: `Remember=true, Remember=false`, т.е, для первого ключа указано `true`, для второго - `false`. Но у меня два раза добавить ключ в коллекцию `Dictionary`, естественно, не получается (ошибка).

Comment: Начнем с того, что у вас в JSON, что вы нам дали, указано `"Domain":"site.ru"`, а вы пишете сейчас `e.site.ru`, уж определитесь. Далее, вам достаточно всего 1-2-х Cookie для авторизации, зачем десериализировать весь словарь? Найдите нужную, зайдите на сайт через Postman и уже затем пишите код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в JSON `e.site.ru`, это я когда сюда выкладывал намудрил, извиняюсь. На счет остального - сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо.

Comment: [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) проделайте и выясните, что именно требует ваш сайт. Не пишите код сразу, сначала анализируйте, ибо я на 90% уверен, что большинство того, что вы понаписали сейчас - лишнее (`UserAgent`, `AcceptEncoding`, `AutomaticDecompression`, `AllowAutoRedirect`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в общем, попробовал я всё это проделать в Postman, штука удобная, но в принципе, ничего не изменилось. 1) Отправляю `get` запрос на страницу авторизации; 2) Беру в исходнике этой страницы токен; 3) Отправляю все данные (токен, логин, пароль) `post` запросом, приходит правильный ответ с куками (вижу свои данные); 4) Отправляю `get` запрос на главную страницу с одной кукой (токен) - авторизация НЕ УДАЛАСЬ, добавляю к этой куке вторую куку `.ASPXAUTH` - авторизация УДАЛАСЬ. Позже выяснил, что можно только одну куку `.ASPXAUTH` добавлять и она будет "подтягивать" за собой вторую.

Comment: А у меня по коду, загружается только кука с токеном.. сейчас попробую как-нибудь принудительно загружать `.ASPXAUTH`

Comment: `ничего не изменилось` - а должно было? Она вам помогла выяснить именно то, что необходимо отправить этому сайту для успешной авторизации, все лишнее теперь можете убрать, включая сериализацию/десериализацию всей коллекции печенек, достаточно лишь значение этого `.ASPXAUTH` в виде простой строки). Также мне не нравиться эта строка - `handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);` (вангую, что там теряется адрес), а также мне не нравиться то, что вы не устанавливаете `BaseAdress` (с которым связываются Cookie). Попробуйте нечто [такое](https://pastebin.com/FvsNUQGv).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо большое, всё сделал как вы сказали, записываю в файл вообще теперь только сам ключ и всё. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Закрывайте тогда вопрос своим ответом, напишите там то, что получили в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

Для правильной загрузки кук (конкретно для моего сайта), нужно было сохранять лишь одну куку — `.ASPXAUTH`, а потом её подгружать.

Итоговый код получился такой:

```
private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true
};
private static readonly Uri baseUri = new Uri("https://e.site.ru");
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseUri };

public static async void SaveCookies()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filename = Path.Combine(path, "test/cookies.bin");

    var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(baseUri);

    using var sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false);
    // сохраняется лишь сам ключ, без имени
    await sw.WriteAsync(cookies[1].Value);
}

public static async void LoadCookies()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filename = Path.Combine(path, "test/cookies.bin");

    using var sr = new StreamReader(filename);
    var cookie_value = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

    handler.CookieContainer.Add(baseUri, new Cookie(".ASPXAUTH", cookie_value));
}
```

Comment: Статика то тут зачем?) Старайтесь ее использовать как можно меньше. Также помните про такую вещь, как DRY - не повторяйся, к примеру, у вас `path` и `filename` повторяются, почему бы не вынести их и не сделать общими? Также не понимаю людей, которые использую `Stream`, ок, оптимизация, но чего вы оптимизировать собрались, запись одного простого текстового значения в файл? Не экономте на спичках, используйте то, что удобней (File.WriteAllText(filename, "ключ"), все, одна строка сделала то, что вы делаете через `Stream`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я как-то и не подумал про System.IO.File, действительно, его будет разумнее здесь использовать. А про путь к файлам, скажу, что в данном проекте мне было без разницы (просто тестовый проект), сам алгоритм буду использовать совсем в другом проекте. Про статику вы где имеете ввиду? В методах? Или в объявлении переменных?

Comment: Из всего, что в вашем коде, статичным должен быть только объект `HttpClient`, да и все.

Comment: Также знаете какая у вас уязвимость в коде? `cookies[1].Value` - с чего вы взяли, что нужная Cookie будет всегда по индексу 1? Советую искать явно, по названию, иначе малейшее обновление на сайте, новая кука у них и все, ваш алгоритс упал.

Comment: Спасибо, поправлю. А чем плох статичный метод? Ну, так проще его использовать, не нужно создавать экземпляр.

Comment: Есть такая вещь, как ООП, также есть такая вещь, как SOLID. Первый говорит, что вы должны строить приложение на основе отдельных объектов, то есть, есть у вас человек - это объект, к примеру его сердце - объект, мозг - объект и т.д. Каждый объект имеет свой функционал, сердце допустим качать кровь. SOLID - это набор правил, где S - это единственная ответственность (каждый метод должен делать что-то одно), а O - это принципы открытости и закрытости (ваш класс должен отдавать наружу только необходимые органы управления).

Comment: И вот теперь давайте подумаем, ваш класс по отправке запросов, это объект, или простой набор методов (я их называю утилитами)? Я считаю его самостоятельным объектом, который должен хранить в себе например коллекцию Cookie, должен хранить в себе базовый адрес, который будет задан при его инициализации, у него есть органы управления, которые должны идти наружу (загрузка и сохранение). Сейчас у вас просто набор методов, которые доступны из всего приложения, любой имеет к ним доступ и любой может загрузить/сохранить. Это не есть хорошо, этот класс нарушает ооп, его трудно тестировать и так далее.

Comment: Ну, а как быть тогда, если мне этот класс нужно вызывать в разных формах, например, но при этом мне не нужен новый экземпляр класса. Если я буду использовать паттерн singleton, то получается поменял шыло на мыло? Или какой-то совсем иной подход?

Comment: [Синглтон != static](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/322228/220553). А так, ну давайте подумаем. К примеру, у вас есть класс `A`, ему необходим класс `B` для работы, так почему класс `A` может создаваться без класса `B`? Человека не будет без сердца) Сейчас вы помните, что человеку требуется это сердце, сделаете перерыв от проекта, забудете, что там и как и потом будете делать `new Person()`, а он требует сердце, которое вы ему не инициализировали. Согласитесь, это не есть хорошо. Поэтому, если классу нужен другой класс, то требуйте его через конструктор - это самый лучший и безопасный способ.

Comment: То есть, сделали класс, отвечающий за всякие эти POST/GET запросы, сделали однажды его объект `private HttpService httpService = new HttpService();`, все, дальше передавайте его в нужные вам классы, где вы его используете, например, `var login = new Login(httpService);`, где сам класс `Login` будет в себе иметь конструктор, принимающий ссылку `private HttpService httpService; public Login(HttpService httpService) => this.httpService = httpService;`. Без каких-либо синглтонов и статики. Лаконично и понятно. А если вам не нравиться вечно писать `new ...`, то IoC в помощь, используйте контейнер.

Comment: Сейчас не понял что-то. Есть класс А, ему необходим класс В для работы.. чет я запутался. Класс А создавался когда класса В ещё в помине не было :) можете, если не затруднит, привести пример? upd: вижу пример, спасибо. Попробую завтра всё переделать, с учётом ваших замечаний

Comment: Я имею ввиду [это](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J64Hmf).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я вот сделал как вы сказали, но у меня выходит что: класс А зависит от логики класса В, а класс В зависит от логики класса А. И как в таком случае инициализировать класс? Думаю, вы поняли.

Comment: Ну это значит, что у вас проблемы в вашей архитектуре. Вон пример выше, человек должен знать про сердце и его состояние, а вот сердце - это самостоятельный компонент. Или ваш класс из вопроса по управлению запросами, он должен знать о том, что находится, например в форме, которая по клику вызывает его метод? Нет, он должен лишь выполнить логику и отдать результат. В программировании все должно быть простым и не замысловатым. А если у вас А зависит от B, который зависит от А, то это уже явно не простая логика и вы явно делаете в одном из этих классов что-то, что не относиться к его обязанностям

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, всё, я понял, спасибо. Я действительно в одном из классов делал то, что не относится к его обязанностям.